# if i deleted my project but i have that in my github so did i have to re install all the dependencies again or just run npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

My question is if i deleted my project but i have that in my github  so did i have to re install all the dependencies again or just run npm install? i formeted my pc so i project lost away but before formet i uploaded my project on github so do i have to download all  dependencies again or just run npm install? i have  dependencies of nodejs react native and choco socketio and some more so that i can do downlaod everthing again or just npm install and all  dependencies will be install by npm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you run `git clone [REPO_URL]` if all dependencies are listed in package.json then running `npm install` in cloned project directory will install all dependencies